# Windows CMD Variable Not Set on First Run

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

I'm using this command on the Windows 10 Command Prompt to check if a folder exists and if it doesn't, create it. The weird thing is, it doesn't work the first time I enter it but the second, third, etc. it does, as if the variable values don't update the first time I run it.

### Command

```
set "folder=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\New folder" &&
set "subfolder=new" &&
( IF exist "%folder%\%subfolder%" ( echo The "%subfolder%" subfolder already exists. ) 
ELSE ( mkdir "%folder%\%subfolder%" && echo Created the "%subfolder%" subfolder. ) )
```

1st execution output:

```
The "%subfolder%" subfolder already exists.
```

That output is wrong. The subfolder doesn't exist because it hasn't been created yet. Why doesn't the variable get expanded?

2nd execution output:

```
Created the "new" subfolder.
```

That's what it should say the first time.

3rd execution output:

```
The "new" subfolder already exists.
```

That's what it should say the second time.

How can I fix the command so it runs right the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. In your example you posted *four lines*. However, because the first two lines ends in `&&` and the fourth one starts in `ELSE` (that it is not a valid command), I *assume* that your example is *really* one long line...

If so, then your code will work if you just split it in these two *separate* lines:

```
set "folder=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\New folder" && set "subfolder=new"
IF exist "%folder%\%subfolder%" ( echo The "%subfolder%" subfolder already exists. ) ELSE ( mkdir "%folder%\%subfolder%" && echo Created the "%subfolder%" subfolder. )
```

If you want to know the reasons for this change, then you should search for "Delayed expansion" term in this or any other cmd.exe commands related site. A brief summary is this:

You can *not* define a variable and %expand% it *in the same line*. To do so, you need to Enable Delayed Expansion and use exclamation marks instead of percent signs to expand `!variable!` values that had changed in the same line.

Comment: Also, It's normal practice to have a `setlocal` command directly after the initial `@echo off`. This discards any changes made to the environment when the batch ends, so variables established by one batch file do not affect any further batches that may be run in the same session. Thus the values are being `set` during the first run but start off as *undefined* and hence *empty* but on subsequent runs start with the value set up in the first run.

Comment: @Magoo: yes, you are right if the commands are placed _in a Batch.bat file_. However, in this case the OP is _"using this command on the Windows 10 Command Prompt"_, so there is not any Batch file here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use for parameters to use the updated values for your variables.
In the code below I have shortened the folder/subfolder names to "A" and "B".

```
set "folder=A" & set "subfolder=B" & @for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %F in ('set folder') do @if "%F"=="folder" @for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %K in ('set subfolder') do @if "%K"=="subfolder" @if exist "%G\%L" (echo The "%L" Subfolder already exists.) else (mkdir "%G\%L" && echo Created the "%L" subfolder.)
```

The same but now split into 4 lines for better readability.
Note: the code below will fail, the code belongs on one line to be runnable!

```
set "folder=A" & set "subfolder=B" &
 @for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %F in ('set folder') do @if "%F"=="folder"
 @for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %K in ('set subfolder') do @if "%K"=="subfolder"
 @if exist "%G\%L" (echo The "%L" Subfolder already exists.) else (mkdir "%G\%L" && echo Created the "%L" subfolder.)
```

This code is closest to the original code of the poster.
But this code can be simplified by leaving out all of the set/for/if stuff and use only for parameters.

rem the next variant uses forparams enclosed in double quot's

```
for %G in ("A") do for %L in ("B") do  @if exist "%~G\%~L" (echo The %L Subfolder already exists.) else (mkdir "%~G\%~L" && echo Created the %L subfolder.)
```

rem the next variant uses forparams not enclosed in double quot's

```
for /F %G in ("A") do for /F %L in ("B") do  @if exist "%G\%L" (echo The "%L" Subfolder already exists.) else (mkdir "%G\%L" && echo Created the "%L" subfolder.)
```